# Jcarousel slider to show only one picture in center in sliderbox

Tags: php, jquery, jcarousel

I'm trying to configure the [jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_auto.html) slider to show only one picture and it is in center. ie, The slider should show single image, and, on a certain time period the next pic should come, and pics should be aligned in center in the slider box.

Now the pics are coming as in the provided link. But when there is only a single pic, its aligned to the left side of slider box. I need in aligned in center.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the same page at buttom are all options of jCarousel..
Look at them to find out the correct options for your case.

If I understand it correct you must set:

```
jQuery('#yourID').jcarousel({
    auto: 10,
    scroll: 1
});
```

where auto is the time for changing the pictures and scroll is the number of shown items.

All positions center/left/right you can fix with CSS.

Comment: Thank you. I were already added it to show single pic. But I need to align pics to the center too. Anyway I found out a way. adding 


.jcarousel-skin-tango li{ text-align: center; }


to styles will solve issue. :)